# How to know control ID based on searched InnerText/Name

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

```
public class UIRow0jqxGrid1Pane : HtmlDiv
    {

        public UIRow0jqxGrid1Pane(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "row0jqxGrid1";//This ID will be dynamic. Need to search based on provided InnerText
            this.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "XXXX";
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = null;
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "id=\"row0jqxGrid1\" role=\"row\" style=\"height: 25px; ;\"";
            this.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "696";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Test");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public HtmlDiv UIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane == null))
                {
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane = new HtmlDiv(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "XXXX";
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = null;
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "style=\"text-align: left;  padding-bottom: 2px; margin- " +
                        "margin-right: 2px; margin- -ms-text-\"";
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "700";
                    this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane.WindowTitles.Add("Test;
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private HtmlDiv mUIALMONDESTATECONSULTAPane;
        #endregion
    }
```

Scenario ____ The above code generated when I select a Item from grid. I notice that items are identified as 'Pane' in grid. Now for different scenario I have to select different item. All my input value stored in a file from where I pick up one value and pass to test method.

What I want ____ I need to find the row id of grid based on my provided value, so that mouse click happen on that row.

What I did ____ The grid populate with data retrieve from database. so I can't assume which value will have what row id. I have change InnerText SearchProperty but then playback stop and test fail.

What I notice in HTML ____The HTML structure is this

```
<grid id="grid1" style="....">
  <div>Header Row definition</div>
  <div> Data Row
    <div id="gridRow0" style="...">A</div>
    <div id="gridRow1" style="...">B</div>
    <div id="gridRow2" style="...">C</div>
    <div id="gridRow3" style="...">D</div>
    .......
    ......
  </div>
</grid>
```

Please give some solution...I did not find any clue...

Thanks for your time...

Comment: you could iterate all the rows in a grid and cmopare to the supplied value - when a match is found pass pass it as a control to the mouse.Click(control) method. to get the control use the GetChildren() method on the grid control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd refactor your code.  You've already got the Id of the row in your HTML, so let's use that.  The TestBuilder tends to make things a bit more difficult to read and includes too many properties to make searching efficient or meaningful.

So, your .uitest file has two sub classes:  .designer.cs (where your code above is located), and a .cs file.  Open the .cs file and locate your row by doing something like:

```
public HtmlDiv gridRow(int index)
{
     HtmlDiv target = new HtmlDiv(browser);
     target.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyName.Id, "gridRow" + index.ToString());
     return target;
}
```

Then, in your test, if you want to get a certain row, just call myMap.gridRow(2) to get the HtmlDiv of that particular row.

Then, if you've got a hyperlink, for example, within that row, in your map you would create the object:

```
public HtmlHyperlink linkOnRow(int index)
{
    HtmlHyperlink target = new HtmlHyperlink(gridRow(index));
    target.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.[your prop], [your value]);
    return target;
}
```

Still, if you wanted to use the innerText, you'd just change `PropertyName.Id` to `PropertyName.InnerText` and use its value instead.

Comment: Thanks Ryan...
with your advice I use this 
<code>
public HtmlDiv gridRow(string innerText, UITestControl browser)
{
      HtmlDiv target = new HtmlDiv(browser);
      target.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText, innerText);
      return target;
}

public string RowId(HtmlDiv htmlDiv)
{
     string rowID = htmlDiv.GetProperty("Id").ToString();
     return rowID;
}
</code>
Thanks...

Comment: Glad it worked!  Please mark the answer if you're satisfied :)